# Cannot run TCP server on iOS, cellular

Tags: ios, c, tcp, tcplistener, cellular-network

I am trying to run a TCP server on iOS from Cellular. For purposes of asking this question, I wrote this very simplified version of a server and client in C using socket/bind/listen/accept/etc. This works fine when I run the server program from a server. When I run the server program from an iOS app via Cellular (no Wifi), the client never connects to the server. Here is my code:

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "tcp_server_IPv4.h"

#define SZ_SOCKADDR_IN sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)

void pfail(char *w) {
    printf("pfail %s\n", w);
    perror(w);
    exit(1);
}

void *tcp_server_IPv4_thread_routine(void *arg) {

    int tcp4_sockfd = 0, tcp4_new_fd = 0;
    char wes[64];
    tcp4_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr = {0};

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = {0};
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(0);

    int br = bind(tcp4_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, SZ_SOCKADDR_IN);
    if (br ==  -1) {
        pfail("PROBLEM BINDING");
    }

    int lr = listen(tcp4_sockfd, 5);
    if (lr == -1) {
        pfail("PROBLEM LISTENING");
    }

    socklen_t gsn_len = sizeof(serv_addr);
    int gsn = getsockname(tcp4_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &gsn_len);
    if (gsn == -1) pfail("getsockname");

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &serv_addr, wes, sizeof(wes));
    printf("start listening on (%s) port (%d)...", wes, ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));
    int tcp_running = 1;
    while (tcp_running) {  // main accept() loop
        socklen_t sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        tcp4_new_fd = accept(tcp4_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (tcp4_new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.sin_family, &their_addr.sin_addr, wes, sizeof wes);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", wes);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(tcp4_sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(tcp4_new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(tcp4_new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(tcp4_new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }
    pthread_exit("exiting fire_up_tcp thread normally");
}

void start_tcp_server_IPv4() {
    pthread_t tcpt4;
    char *w4 = "TCP server IPv4 thread";
    int pr4 = pthread_create(&tcpt4, NULL, tcp_server_IPv4_thread_routine, (void *)w4);
    if (pr4) pfail("create thread for fire_up_tcp_server_v4");
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT_NUMBER 57020
#define SERVER_ADDRESS  "70.208.71.248"

#define MAXDATASIZE 200 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    char ip_str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("client: socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in sa_server = {0};
    sa_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_ADDRESS, &(sa_server.sin_addr));
    sa_server.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa_server.sin_addr, ip_str, sizeof ip_str);

    printf("Try connecting to (%s)(%d)\n", ip_str, ntohs(sa_server.sin_port));

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error on connect --> %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("CLIENT::Connection successful.");

    char fr[128];
    sprintf(fr, "Some text here to send");
    if (send(sockfd, fr, sizeof fr, 0) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error on send --> %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Results from running getifaddrs() on the iOS device. All pdp_ip addresses are up and running:

```
(interface)(family)(ip)

(lo0)(2)(127.0.0.1)
(lo0)(30)(::1)
(lo0)(30)

(pdp_ip0)(2)(100.114.61.107)
(pdp_ip0)(30)(fe80::4d5:31ee:ba73:d63a)
(pdp_ip0)(30)(2600:1001:b101:600d:1076:2a12:b461:2a02)
(pdp_ip0)(30)(2600:1001:b101:600d:89e3:c982:c32a:b6b2)

(pdp_ip2)(30)(fe80::18b6:a5a7:33a2:13f6)
(pdp_ip2)(30)(2600:1001:812f:cec5:49:69a:d1b9:cc47)
(pdp_ip2)(30)(2600:1001:812f:cec5:e936:25c5:702:e067)
(pdp_ip2)(30)(2600:1001:812f:cec5:48de:1765:5cb5:d56c)

(en2)(30)(fe80::10d5:2496:594f:ff72)
(en2)(2)(169.254.249.210)
(ipsec1)(30)(fe80::26f0:94ff:fe9a:50bc)
(utun0)(30)(fe80::99a1:9bf7:428e:8166)
(utun1)(30)(fe80::4b1d:be95:bbf2:bf02)
(utun2)(30)(fe80::1748:1a1a:c5ee:bda9)
(utun3)(30)(fe80::d3c1:79bc:7613:ffb)
(utun4)(30)(fe80::d3c8:e837:ba74:67dc)
```

Comment: Some network operators use internal IP addresses and NAT to get to the outside. Then you cannot easily reach any server as you don't have port forwarding to your mobile device. Also can you be sure that the mobile device has a PDP context/default bearer activated and has a PDN connection at that time?

Comment: Verify you're not in Carrier-grade NAT.

Comment: Thank you @Gerhardh . If I switch to IPv6, then is it true that this server should be reachable? Regarding, PDP context, when I run getifaddrs(), I see a pdp_ip0 address for IPv4 and a few pdp_ip0 addresses for IPv6. I have added the results of getifaddrs() to the question

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen3 . How can I verify that I'm not in a Carrier-grade NAT?

Comment: @waynemystir you detect CGN by checking if your wan ip matches your interface ip. You will need a remote server to get your wan ip. Eg: https://api.ipify.org/